# SQL Server: "How many orders have been placed by Jamba Juice"? Many to many relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server, many-to-many

I've been stuck on trying to write this query for 2 hours now. Please help.

The questions asks "How many orders have been placed by Jamba Juice"?

And this is what I have.

```
SELECT 
    Customers.customerNumber, Customers.customerName, 
    COUNT(orderNumber) AS orders_placed
FROM 
    Customers
WHERE 
    Customers.customerName = 'Jamba Juice'
JOIN 
    Orders ON Customers.customerNumber = Orders.customerNumber
GROUP BY 
    Customers.customerNumber, Customers.customerName;
```

The error message I?m getting is

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 29
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'JOIN'

Answer (score 1):

`Join` should be before `WHERE`.

```
SELECT Customers.customerNumber, Customers.customerName, COUNT(orderNumber) AS orders_placed
FROM Customers
JOIN Orders ON Customers.customerNumber= Orders.customerNumber
WHERE Customers.customerName= 'Jamba Juice'
GROUP BY Customers.customerNumber, Customers.customerName;
```

Comment: Wow, i feel so dumb. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

your JOIN statement should come right after FROM Customers and before your where clause

```
SELECT Customers.customerNumber, Customers.customerName, COUNT(orderNumber) AS orders_placed

FROM Customers

JOIN Orders ON Customers.customerNumber= Orders.customerNumber

WHERE Customers.customerName= 'Jamba Juice'

GROUP BY Customers.customerNumber, Customers.customerName;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply!!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the syntax error.Please note tables need to join first followed by joining conditions and filter conditions like below.

```
SELECT Customers.customerNumber, Customers.customerName, COUNT(orderNumber) AS orders_placed
FROM Customers
JOIN Orders ON Customers.customerNumber= Orders.customerNumber
WHERE Customers.customerName= 'Jamba Juice'
GROUP BY Customers.customerNumber, Customers.customerName;
```